# Javascript-GPU synchronization in Chrome and Firefox: performance issues

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webgl, emscripten

I use Emscripten to build some rendering code, setting the main loop as follows:

```
emscripten_set_main_loop(emscriptenMainLoop, 0, 1);
```

This yields 60 fps maximum with any scene. Then I load a complex enough scene to make Firefox run at 18-20 fps only, while Chrome performs at 60 fps on the same code.

OK, let's look at a typical single frame in profilers of both browsers.

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Disregarding the efficiency of my emscriptened JS code and efficiency of it's execution (which is a bit better in Chrome), we can see, that an inter-frame delay in Chrome is 1-2 ms long, and sometimes it's even less than a millisecond. The same delay in Firefox is 20 and more milliseconds long. It looks like in Chrome the GPU (green strip at the bottom of the screenshot) runs simultaneously with JS code, while in FF it's synchronous.

Both Windows and Linux browsers exhibit the same behavior. I tested it with OpenGL4.5-capable nVidia cards and latest drivers. Both browsers report hardware accelerated WebGL capability, and Firefox is able to run at 60 fps with a less complex scene. C++ code was built with all possible optimizations and eliminated error checks, i.e. `O3`, `LTO`, `NDEBUG`, `DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1`, `ELIMINATE_DUPLICATE_FUNCTIONS=1`.

Is it possible to change this behavior of Firefox? Maybe it's controlled by a setting in `about:config`? Maybe there is a magical Js or Emscripten call, which sets some Firefox' internals to a right state? Or do I need to turn something off?

Comment: Have you filed a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi)?

Comment: @guest271314 not yet, will do it later.

Comment: Chrome using a multi process renderer. That means all your WebGL commands just generate a command buffer, that command buffer gets run in another process effectively giving you 2 processes running your code. Firefox does not do this, it's running all your code in a single process. There's no simple thing you can do to fix firefox except to get them to spend a few man years re-writing their graphics infrastructure to be multi-process or possibly wait for being able to render from a worker. Both are on their TODO list but neither is a small amount of work.